# Is there a way to plot NLTK bigrams freqdist selected result?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, nlp

I'm trying to plot only the relevant pair of words from the bigram freqdist result
[image: Some of the words here are irrelevant, I'm trying to plot only the pairs that make sense. any insights? Thanks]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the last line as:
tokenized_bg.plot(20) or
tokenized_bg.plot(20, cumulative=True)